# Hashmaps in javascript from integer keys

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I am coding in javascript & I need HashMap type structure . 
Normally when I need hashmaps , I would use associative arrays only (with strings as keys).
But this time I need integers as keys to hashmaps.

So if I try to store A[1000]=obj, 1001 sized array is created & A[1001] is put as obj.
Even if I try A["1000"]=obj , it still allocates 1001 spaces & fills them with undefined.

I dont want that as my keys could be very large ( around 1 mill).
I could use it as A["dummy1000"]=obj but I dont want to use this dirty method.

Anyway of doing it elegantly & with ease too ?

Comment: What makes you think it allocates all that space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing `A[1000] = 1` doesn't create an array with 1000 elements. It creates an array object whose length attribute is 1001, but this is only because the length attribute in JavaScript arrays is defined as the maximum index + 1.

The reason it works like this is so you can do `for(var i = 0; i < A.length; i++)`.

I see you're confused about the allocation of the array. To you it looks like JavaScript has filled the elements with undefined - actually there isn't anything there, but if you try to access any element in an array that hasn't been defined you get `undefined`.

Comment: So you mean to say that even if I do A[1000000]=1 , mem allocated actually is not in order of a mill but only few bytes. & hence it is safe to use A[1000000] during actual run of web ?

Comment: Absolutely. Try it. Try `A[100000000] = 1` and see if you use any more memory than doing `A[0] = 1`.

Comment: That is also why many operations, such as iteration, on this sparse "pseudo array" will be much slower than on small, dense arrays; arrays that are small, or grow only using `push`.

Answer (score 3):

Create a hash code from the key, and use that as index. Make the hash code limited to a small range, so that you get a reasonably small array of buckets.

Something like:

```
function HashMap() {
  // make an array of 256 buckets
  this.buckets = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) this.buckets.push([]);
}

HashMap.prototype.getHash = function(key) {
  return key % 256;
}

HashMap.prototype.getBucket = function(key) {
  return this.buckets[this.getHash(key)];
}

HashMap.prototype.getBucketItem = function(bucket, key) {
  for (var i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
    if (bucket[i].key == key) return i:
  }
  return -1;
}

HashMap.prototype.setItem = function(key, value) {
  var bucket = this.getBucket(key);
  var index = this.getBucketItem(bucket, key);
  if (index == -1) {
    bucket.push({ key: key, value: value });
  } else {
    bucket[index].value = value;
  }
}

HashMap.prototype.getItem = function(key) {
  var bucket = this.getBucket(key);
  var index = this.getBucketItem(bucket, key);
  if (index == -1) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return bucket[index].value;
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: Code is not tested.

Comment: Why in the world would you go to all that trouble?

Comment: There's an existing JS HashMap implementation, written by me: http://code.google.com/p/jshashtable

Comment: @Pointy: For example if you need to use something as key that can't be used in a regular array.

Comment: I like this code a lot. This `HashMap` is simple, and it uses an array as backing store, (theoretically) making many operations on it much much faster than using a standard JS object on which you perform `add` and `delete` operations. It also has a much smaller memory footprint than [@TimDown](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down)'s version. Would like to see a jsperf on this. Since the `buckets` array can be extremely sparse, you might want to consider [storing all set indices in a BitField](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25807014/2228771) or, better yet, grow/shrink dynamically.